# Report now prompts for credentials after making changes

Tags: crystal-reports

Some reports have been updated and work as before (can be viewed through a .net app and not prompt for credentials).

Other reports have started prompting for credentials since they've been changed. This happens even if the change is just moving something on the report.

I've tried deleting everything on the report apart from a label and this hasn't made any difference.

There's no difference in the .net code in how these reports are displayed.

All the reports are using the same DSN datasource.

If the credentials aren't stored in the report, I'm not sure how only changing the report can make this difference?

Update to add: Crystal reports v9.2.2.634

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Came back to this today. Tried changing a report that I'd previously edited and was working OK, just to see if all reports edited after a certain point were going wrong, and this worked fine.

Tried altering one of the broken reports again (just adding a space to the end of a label), saved this and that report now works fine.

No idea what actually made this work, but if you get the same problem you could try editing a previously edited working report and trying again.

Confused.